# How can I store printers locally?

Tags: printing, configuration, settings

I usually upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu by making a clean install. I do use a separate `/home` partition, so most of my application settings stay in place.

One thing that bothers me though, is that I have to reinstall my network printer each time I upgrade my Ubuntu. I would like to get rid of this by storing this printer's configuration locally, just like the other applications.

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

The installed printers are stored in `/etc/cups/printers.conf`, and their drivers in `/etc/cups/ppd/*.ppd`.

I don't know if there's a way to tell cups to store printer configuration in another location, but you can backup those files before re-installation:

```
sudo service cups stop
mkdir ~/cups-bkp
sudo cp -a /etc/cups/printers.conf /etc/cups/ppd/ ~/cups-bkp/
sudo service cups start
```

And restore them after re-installation:

```
sudo service cups stop
sudo cp -a ~/cups-bkp/* /etc/cups/
sudo service cups start
```

Comment: symlinking is a method ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Didn't work. I've stopped cups and symlinked /etc/cups/printers.conf to /home/username/cups-bkp/printers.conf. I started cups, opened "Printers" and... there was nothing! Weird.